# Hosting a WCF service using net tcp binding. Error: Service metadata may not be accessible

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

I have a Service Application which has the following web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

  <standardEndpoints>
  </standardEndpoints>
  <bindings>
  </bindings>
  <services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="metadatabehaviour" name="WCF_Service.HistorianService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="WCF_Service.IHistorianCollectorService" />
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8081/mex" binding="mexTcpBinding"
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8081" binding="netTcpBinding"
      contract="WCF_Service.IHistorianCollectorService" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="metadatabehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

 <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
 </system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
 </system.webServer>

 </configuration>
```

And I am getting the following error: Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.

I can successfully run the service if I am just implementing the "basicHttpBinding" but as soon as I introduce a "netTcp" binding, I start getting this error. I have changed the 'mex' binding to 'mexTcpBinding' but still the error persists.
I have tried toggling the relevant properties. Any idea how I can correct this error?

Comment: Can you run the service if you add only second net.tcp endpoint?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka- No, I'm not able to run the service even with only net.tcp endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution. My port number for net.tcp had value '0'. I didnt know that was possible. Changing it to 808 did it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you actually disabled metadata exchange:

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
```

It should be set to true!

Comment: @Vitaliy- That would be true if I were hosting just HTTP endpoints. If I have to use net.tcp binding, that property has to be false. Anyway i still tried to put it to true, but to no avail.